# Facebook Analytics page views

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-analytics

When I load my web page, I am logging an app view event using the Facebook SDK as such:

```
window.FB.AppEvents.logPageView()
```

If I have the URL of the page from which I logged that page view. How do I programmatically get the page view count for that particular URL/page? Is there a Graph API request I can make or maybe some method on the Facebook Web SDK I can use to get such data?

Answer (score 0):

There's no Graph API to retrieve this data, you can use the Facebook Analytics UI at facebook.com/analytics